# Canvas app issue

Tags: canvas

I was playing with Canvas app in my **Trailhead Play Ground (TP)**. I have implemented Canvas in TP successfully but very time I have received below error.

[image]

[image]

However, I have implemented same Canvas app in my **Developer Org (DE)** and getting proper output from Canvas.

Is there any known issue in TP regarding Canvas? Any idea how to fix it in TP?

PS: I was implementing Canvas app from below link: http://www.worldofsalesforce.com/2017/05/displaying-external-web-app-using-Salesforce-Canvas.html

Comment: Do you have the pUsername and Password for your play ground org](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/trailhead_playground_management/units/get-your-trailhead-playground-username-and-password)? I've found references that suggest Canvas apps don't work with certain authentication methods. E.g. [frontdoor.jsp](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AmRnIAK). So it might be worth a direct login.

Comment: Thanks @DanielBallinger. As you know, generally Play ground orgs are getting authenticated by Trailhead Account. So play ground orgs don't need passwords to login. I will do password reset of one of my Play ground org so that I can login using username/password and test the Canvas.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Tested with username/password and its working as expected. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found other posts that suggest [Canvas apps don't work when you are logged into an org using frontdoor.jsp](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AmRnIAK).

The direct login to Trailhead playground orgs will has a similar process.

Instead, try and authenticate into the playground directly with the username and password. These can be recovered using the instructions in [Get Your Trailhead Playground Username and Password](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/trailhead_playground_management/units/get-your-trailhead-playground-username-and-password)

Comment: Tested with username/password and its working as expected. Many thanks.

Comment: Also, I have mailed trailhead@salesforce.com (Trailhead Support) to get their advice on this.